# Unable to send mail using 465 port for smtp.gmail.com host

Tags: c#, smtp, mailmessage, networkcredentials

In my aplication,I am sending mail using smtp server.
As i am able to send mail from gmail smtp server with 25 and 587 port no but when i am using 465 port smtp server not able to send mail and goes into process for infinite time
i am using below code to send mail.

```
MailMessage   mailmsg;
SmtpClient client;

client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
mailmsg  = new MailMessage();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyID@gmail.com", "Password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
mailmsg.From = new MailAddress("MyID@gmail.com");

mailmsg.To.Add("Abc@yahoo.com");

client.Send(mailmsg);
```

I am not able detect the problem.Can any one have Solution
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Port 465 is SSL port for the gmail SMTP. You need to activate SSL to use this port.

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

I think it should work (can't test it right now).

Comment: i have already tested with client.EnableSsl = true but its it does not solve my problem

Comment: Can you launch your code in debug and go step by step to see where the process freeze? Maybe it can help us to see why does it bug with this port and not another... And then why use 465 when 587 port works? Do you have any particular use of one over another?

Answer (score 0):

set a timeout.

client.Timeout = 10000;

It will now come back in 10 seconds with the failure instead of waiting forever.